# Field names in content editor are wrong (multiple colons and no capitalisation) but fine in VS

Tags: content-editor, templates, visual-studio

I have a situation where I have a template and thus content items of that template whereby the field names seem to have problems in the content editor but not in visual studio.

Notice below that city and postal code both have 2 colons and postal code is not properly capitalised.

[image: Content Editor]

But Visual Studio seems to show these field names just fine, and everywhere I look, everything seems fine.

[image: Visual Studio]

As a note, there is no complex template inheritance happening. The template where this occurs is derived only from Standard template and the fields in question are Template fields.

Additionally, I can access the field values using their correct names. One example being `item["Postal Code"]`, but the field name still displays incorrectly in the content editor.

I have already tried deleting the fields and then re-adding them, and the problem still persists. I also created brand new content items from the template after the changes, and the problem still persists.

I would and could delete the template and start over, but the template in question has a lot of fields and a lot of validation happening on each field, so I'd rather not restart.

Thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Did you at some point have a : in the field name? Does this only happen for City and Postal code fields? What happens when you add a Random named field like Test or Testing?

Comment: Check the `Title` field on the field items, does that have anything in?

Comment: @ASURA there may have been a : at some point, but I can't confirm it. When I add a new field called Testing Field, it displays with no issue. @Richard Seal , the `Title` field on the field item does not have anything in it. None of the other fields that are working fine have a value in that field either. It seems as though Sitecore is hung up or having problems with those specific field names in this case. Perhaps it's a bug as a result of renaming or reordering in the past? Thanks!

Comment: Can you do the following in an incognito browser - Can you add a value in the title field save and then remove it and save. Also change the field name to City1 save and rename back to City and save?

Comment: In the incognito browser I performed the change to the field item title field as you recommended. The problem still persisted even after creating a new content item. Here is the interesting part. When I changed the name to City 1 and Postal Code 1, the field names displayed properly... But when I changed the field names back, they reverted back to their buggy state, as if there is some particular fixation on the exact field names "City" and "Postal Code"

Comment: Could you please try following:
1) Click on your template
2) Click on View -> Raw Values
3) See if the names match your expectation or not

I just created a sample template with those exact fields and it looked fine. Also what is the field type for those fields that have extra : in them?

Comment: Hi @AkshayMahajan, yes the field names appear fine when viewing the raw values.

Comment: Do you by chance have more than one language version of that template? Also, look at the items that represent template fields—do those have any language versions apart from English?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, the item and its fields are generally very simple, so there is only one version and the language is English. I have previously done a version reset which didn't help at all. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Marcel Just to make sure you understood me correctly. I am not talking about about the item that uses the template. I am talking about the template itself—it could potentially have multiple language versions (although it is a bad practice to do that).

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko thank you for the clarification. I can confirm that both the content item and template do not have multiple language versions.

Comment: @Marcel Could you create a package with the template, upload it somewhere and link it to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you have a matching item in /sitecore/System/Dictionary/.

I did a quick test by adding a Dictionary item that matches the name of a field and the Content Editor picks it up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, you're definitely right. I was able to find an exact dictionary item with a phrase that exactly matched the fudged field names. Thank you. We are currently working out a solution as we are not quite sure what to do with the dictionary item, why it's there, and so on. Will return back to this question as soon as possible.

Comment: Great answer Jonas, nice find.  @Marcel don't forget, if this answer solves your problem, be sure to select it as the correct answer. =)

Comment: As a side note, whenever you're deploying dictionary items upstream, Sitecore caches the dictionary items. Some versions of Sitecore require this cache to be cleared for the updates to come through.